# [ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: ]

Tags: rest, api, docusignapi

No matter what I specify in the Envelope definition, I am getting [ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: ] when I call envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope, but notice the error description is blank.

DocuSign.eSign.dll 3.0.1.0 is installed. ASP website project. Seems like an account setup issue, but difficult to debug with no description. I am successfully logging in. I am using the sample code from the REST API getting started guide.

[ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: ]
DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition, CreateEnvelopeOptions options) +1836
DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition, CreateEnvelopeOptions options) +72
DocuSignApiTest.CreateEnvelope() in C:\Users\David\Dropbox (SoundEquity)\Sound Equity\Technology\WebSite-v10-SEAZ\Communication\GenerateDocs.aspx.vb:1073
GenerateDocs.btnDocuSignTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\David\Dropbox (SoundEquity)\Sound Equity\Technology\WebSite-v10-SEAZ\Communication\GenerateDocs.aspx.vb:893
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782354
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35

Answer (score 0):

you are using a very old version of the SDK. Please upgrade to latest version 4.0.0. If you still get an error at that point - please let us know here.